# Using Perl regex over multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to replace all occurrences of this in a file:

```
ab
ba
```

With this:

```
a a
```

I tried the obvious:

```
$ perl -i -p -e 's/ab\nba/a a/' file.txt
```

With no success. How is this done?

I can't find any questions that properly articulate this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any other options, `-p` processes the input line by line. No line can contain anything after the `\n`. You have to change the record separator:

```
perl -i~ -0pe 's/ab\nba/a a/' file.txt
```

- `-i~` will modify the file "in place", leaving a backup behind (named `file.txt~`)
- `-0` makes the character `\0` the input record separator. The important thing is it doesn't occur in the string to be replaced, so it will never read just a part of it.
- `-p` reads the file record by record, and after reading each, it runs the code and prints the default variable `$_`
- `-e` just introduces the code.

Comment: Finally, what I was looking for - to add `apply plugin` to the top of all my `build.gradle` files. I thought `/s` would work but `s{^}{apply plugin}s` replaces the beginning of every line and I don't understand why.